# ANIMATION NODES_ PLAY ANIMATION IN COLLECTION

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to reproduce the earth animation from this tut : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEYI4lnOprY

At the end, some arcs are animated. I have this node tree :
[image]

My problem is that i'dont get the animation when i play it on the timeline. The tutorial is from blender 2.79 and it was the object group system instead of the collection one of the 2.8x.
So i have replaced the "object from group" node by "collection info" on the upper left of the screen capture and it react good when i change values in the bevel start of the "Curve Object Output" (on the right), but if i plug the "Map Range" to it, nothing happen and normally it should play the animation. I tried to change "object" by "Collection list" in the "Loop Input" but i'can't plug it to the "curve object Node". I'm a beginner in AN, and if someone could tell me what i should do it would be great. Thanx !

Comment: Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting and is considered rude.

Comment: My bad, I didn't even think about it when I wrote that ‍♂️